# Web-Application with CORS Origin: * using authorization header

Tags: web-application, authorization, same-origin-policy, cors, header

As stated here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS at "Credentialed requests and wildcards". Quote:

> When responding to a credentialed request, the server must specify an
>   origin in the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, instead
>   of specifying the "*" wildcard.
>
> Because the request headers in the above example include a Cookie
>   header, the request would fail if the value of the
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header were "*". But it does not fail:
>   Because the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is
>   "http://foo.example" (an actual origin) rather than the "*" wildcard,
>   the credential-cognizant content is returned to the invoking web
>   content.

So if I read this correctly, if the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to `*`. CORS requests can't be accomplished with credentials, so - for example with a `Authorization: Bearer 123` header.

This only applies if the request comes from an different origin, than the web-application (SOP). Otherwise it would be impossible for a web-application to use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Authorization: Token 123`.

Did I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much, yes. The key here is that the browser doesn't pay any attention to the ACAO header for requests to the same domain: therefore you can put anything you like in the ACAO header, and it'll work for your application running on the same domain.

For requests to a different domain, the browser does pay attention to the ACAO header - if the origin is acceptable, it then looks at what other `Access-Control` headers are included, and takes action based on those (e.g. ignoring authentication headers if there is a wildcard, or no `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header)